# Rails controller subtract a quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update the attributes of a related model.

The model record being created is `invitem` the related model record is `matitem`.

This is the code I'm trying in the `invitem` controller:

```
  def create
    @invitem = Invitem.new(params[:invitem])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invitem.matitem_id != nil
        Matitem.find(@invitem.matitem_id).update_attributes(:qty => (:qty - @invitem.units))
      end
      if @invitem.save
```

Rails doesn't like the way I'm trying to subtract `@invitem.units` from `:qty`

I get

```
undefined method `-' for :qty:Symbol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to first assign your `Matitem` result to an object so you can access its quantity:

```
matitem = Matitem.find(@invitem.matitem_id)
matitem.update_attributes(:qty => (matitem.qty - @invitem.units))
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be cleaner to use ''decrement'' method:

```
Matitem.find(@invitem.matitem_id).decrement!(:qty, @invitem.units)
```

Edit: additionally you should think of rewriting the controller method. The decrement operation seems to be part of model logic. Use the before_create callback in the Invitem model to decrement the associated matitem.qty if present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@invitem.matitem.update_attribute(:qty, (@invitem.matitem.qty - @invitem.units))
```